# Changes to one Unity trail renderer causes all of them to flicker

Tags: unity, trail-renderer

I'm using Unity. So I have a prefab, and this prefab has a trail renderer component attached to it.

However, for some of the game objects I want to stop the trailer renderer at certain points in time. But doing so seems to make all of the trail renderers blink; flash off and on. I've tried changing time, disabling the component, and using Clear() while hiding the trail renderer behind the background before needing to be used. All of these makes all trail renderers flicker on the frame the change happens.

I believe providing the code won't be helpful, it's just if(x) disable-action, if(y) enable_action. What can I do?

Comment: Are disabling Trail Renderer component for that??

Comment: How are you disabling it? Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in Unity 5.3.3. The following is the bug tracker entry.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/trailrenderer-flickers-and-does-not-render-at-all-times