# Unity Trail Renderer artifacts — flickering & disappearing

Tags: unity, trail-renderer

I have a projectile prefab that have 2 trail renderers attached to it. Whenever I instantiate another projectile, every trail renderer seems to flicker. This is similar to the question: [Changes to one Unity trail renderer causes all of them to flicker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116806/changes-to-one-unity-trail-renderer-causes-all-of-them-to-flicker)

In addition to that, I have other rendering artifacts as well. Having too many trail renderers seems to cause some of them to not draw. Also, sometimes, they just seem to randomly choose not to draw.

[image: As you can see, the left projectile doesnt want to draw its trail.]

As you can see, the left most projectile doesnt want to draw its trail.

[image]

Similarly, adding more projectiles, the front projectiles seems to lose all of its trails.

So thus, the 2 issues I am having is

- Flicking trail renderers when another is instantiated.
- Trails not rendering randomly.

Unity Version: 5.3.2f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Unity 5.3.3. The following is the bug tracker entry.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/trailrenderer-flickers-and-does-not-render-at-all-times